# How to filter rows that have specific character at the end in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I want to get rows that have "/" character at the end of Image column value. So, to make it clear here is the image:

[image]

What formula I have to use to filter rows that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check whether these helps you:**

```
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/750201-excel-filtering-by-last-2-characters-help-needed.html
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/925-excel-sort-last-character.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is easier way to filter it. On Data tab in Excel select Filter and then in parameters of filter choose filter "Ends with..." and specify your character